# Changing C++ Standard Output

Tags: c++, cout

If I understand correctly, `std::cout << "Test";` should output `Test` to the terminal emulator, but when I run a program using it, it instead creates a file called a.out. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Post the code of your program, how you are compiling it, and how you are calling the compiled executable.

Comment: `a.out` is the executable program created by the compiler. You can execute that from a terminal program to print out `test` as you want.

Comment: "it instead creates a file called a.out" Hmm, are you sure you clearly differentiate between your source code and the compiler, and between program output and an executable generated. Have you tried  running that *a.out*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try running the `a.out` file from inside a `Terminal` (if `Linux/Mac`) or `cmd` (if `Windows`) by running the following command:

`./a.out`

If it throws any permission exception in `Linux/Mac` then you should try running the following command first,

`chmod +x ./a.out`

and then run,

`./a.out`